# Ошибка [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'JPEG.OBJ' в RAD C++ Builder 11

Tags: c++, c++builder

Проект делался в С++ Builder 2010 Architect. Мне нужно открыть его в свежей версии 11, но выдаёт данную ошибку. Пробовал менять на версию 10.4, пробовал искать решения в сети. Может кто-то знает решение этой ошибки? Прикладываю фото ошибки
[image: Ошибка][image: ошибка]

Comment: Решение прописать Vcl.Imaging в Unit Scope Names (https://codeverge.com/embarcadero.cppbuilder.nontech/-ilink32-error-fatal-unable-to/1082426) не помогло?

Comment: Он прописан уже был